# Problem when uploading file on google Drive

Tags: apex, visualforce

[image]

I am getting problem like screen shot, when try to upload file using visualforce page. How i can solve this issue please help me get rid with this problem

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: how you are uploading files to google drive?

Comment: i  am uploading file via save to drive button based on below link.https://developers.google.com/drive/web/savetodrive

Answer (score 2):

```
<apex:page wizard="true">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
    <center>
        <div class="g-savetodrive"
         data-src="/img/seasonLogos/2016_winter.png"
         data-filename="2015_winter_sales.gif"
         data-sitename="Salesforce 2015 Winter">
        </div>
    </center>
</apex:page>
```

Create a new VF page and try with above code. Hope this will solve your issue.