# Use Save to drive button with an url from another domain

Tags: visualforce

I am trying to upload an image url from another domain with the Save to drive button of Google. So google tells me that I need to include the following special HTTP headers.

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Range
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Cache-Control, Content-Encoding, Content-Range
Do some one know how I can include this headers in my project?

I get this information from https://developers.google.com/drive/web/savetodrive

Save to Drive Demo: Basic Page

Comment: can you just add complete console error?

Comment: I have added here http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100944/problem-when-uploading-file-on-google-drive

Comment: hey @Raviakant check my Ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<apex:page wizard="true">
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></script>
    <center>
        <div class="g-savetodrive"
         data-src="/img/seasonLogos/2016_winter.png"
         data-filename="2015_winter_sales.gif"
         data-sitename="Salesforce 2015 Winter">
        </div>
    </center>
</apex:page>
```

Try with this code hope this will solve you.

As you can see I am using static image url for saving into google drive

you can make it dynamic. Give a try

If you need to pass the attachment image.

`/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P9000000jhdTQ`

Here pass your attachment id instead of `00P9000000jhdTQ` and pass the url in data-src

```
data-src="your dynamic url"
```

Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: Your code is working fine and thanks for providing such information. but i want to add file from attachment (dynamically) this time it's throwing error which is described by me.

Comment: I will select both best answer if you help me.

Comment: @user9839 check my updated ans. you need to prepare dynamic url with attachment id and pass into `data-src`

Comment: I have do same as you like i have a image on below url   https://c.ap1.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P9000000jFRXN and then i have added this url on data-src="https://c.ap1.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P9000000jFRXN" but it is not working.

Comment: Please Ratan help me , i am stuck on this problem from last three days.Thanks in advance

Comment: not sure but you can get the blob data of that attachment and then store into a string and then use that sting in data-src

Comment: I have implemented this with static resource that will work for you?

Comment: Yes it's working for static resources but it is not working for attachment.

Comment: I want to add attachment and upload this attachment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32343/discussion-between-ratan-and-user9839).